# Access the various elements of each items in a custom item list

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom list in android, this list has a text editor and a check box for each element, I want a method to get the data and the status of each element, and save these in an array of Movie objects, where movie is *Movie(String description, boolean status)*

How to acces the various components of each element of the list?

My custom ListAdapter is

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

       private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> movieCollection =
                new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

       private String[] data;

       public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
          super(context, R.layout.movie_item, android.R.id.text1, context
                   .getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movies));

          data =
                   context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_thumbs);
       }

       public void toggleMovie(int position) {
          if (!isInCollection(position)) {
             movieCollection.put(position, true);
          } else {
             movieCollection.put(position, false);
          }
       }

       public boolean isInCollection(int position) {
          return movieCollection.get(position) == Boolean.TRUE;
       }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View listItem = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      CheckBox checkMark =
               (CheckBox) listItem.findViewById(android.R.id.check_movie);
      checkMark.setChecked(isInCollection(position));

      EditText editText = (EditText) listItem.findViewById(R.id.movie_description;
      editText.setTag(position);
      String textUrl = this.data[position];
      new DownloadTask(position, editText).execute(editText);

      return listItem;
   }
}
```

*If someone haven't understand what is the trouble: 
I need a way to access each EditText and CheckBox in the items of the described list directly.*

Comment: So what are you having trouble with? Or are you just asking someone to do this for you?

Comment: I need a way to access each listed EditText and CheckBox in the items of the list as I wrote. 
I don't ask just to profit the community and this is a new question on stackoverflow. 
If you don't want answer, please don't flame with these insinuation.

Comment: I'm not flaming, you just didn't make the question abundantly clear. You asked for a method, which makes it sound like you want someone to write code the entire method for you so you can just use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save the data after each edit, having a Movie List (or similar) in the adapter and setting listeners to the edit text and the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to access directly the EditText and CheckBox view of each item in the list.